# Create an Event with an ID to Google Calendar: Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, events, calendar

I am trying to add an event to Google Calendar, and I am not getting an event added when doing so. I am sure the code is working around it. Does anyone have any ideas why an event is not being added to the calendar?

I would add the entire code, but I feel like it misses the point.

```
var calendarId = "Typed Out ID of Calendar";
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
calendar.createEvent('Breakfast',
    new Date("April 19, 2021"));
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the endTime. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createEvent(String,Date,Date)

Comment: @Cooper: I tried to type calendar.createEvent('Breakfast', 04/19/2021, 04/20/2021); it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe it's how I am typing in the dates.

Comment: They have to be dates not strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to display your calendar ids:

```
function displayCalendarInfo() {
  var cals=CalendarApp.getAllCalendars();
  var s='Calendar Information';
  for(var i=0;i<cals.length;i++)
  {
    s+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Name: %s Id: %s', cals[i].getName(),cals[i].getId());
  }
  s+='<br /><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s).setWidth(1200).setHeight(450);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Calendar Data');
}
```

Just to make sure that you using the correct id.

Create Event: (It works)

```
function createEvent() {
  const cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('id');
  const start = new Date(2021,3,20,10,30,0,0);//4/20/2021 10:30:00
  const end = new Date(2021,3,20,11,30,0,0);//4/20/2021 11:30:00
  cal.createEvent('new event',start,end);
}
```

Months range from Jan - Dec which is 0 - 11 which one less than you would expect